# 読み込んだcsvファイルに対する処理のエラー

Tags: python, python3

csvファイルのデータを読み込んでその中の最大値を表示させたいのですが下記の通りエラーとなってしまいます。
（csvファイルはオシロスコープで計測したものです）
どなたかご回答よろしくお願いします。

**プログラム**

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
csvfile = r'C:\Users\ryoma\Documents\学習用　python\test1khz.csv'

f=open(csvfile,"r")
reader = csv.reader(f)
data = [v for v in reader]
f.close()

np.max(data)
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b6a52add7c26> in <module>
----> 1 np.max(data)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in amax(a, axis, out, keepdims, initial)
   2503     """
   2504     return _wrapreduction(a, np.maximum, 'max', axis, None, out, keepdims=keepdims,
-> 2505                           initial=initial)
   2506 
   2507 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
     84                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
     85 
---> 86     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
     87 
     88 

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Comment: これ [cannot perform reduce with flexible type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43442415/9014308) と類似かもしれません。`csv`の`reader`ではなく`pandas`の`read_csv`で読み込んでみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: kunifさん　コメントありがとうございます。ご回答の通り pandas で読み込んだら出来ました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

エラーの原因は変数 `data` のリストの末端の要素が文字列であることです。np.sum は基本的には数値の合計を求めるものですから、文字列の合計は定義されておらずエラーとなっていると思われます。data 変数のリストの要素がすべて数値を表す文字列であるなら、以下のように、数値を表す文字列を、数値に変換することができます。これにより、np.sum でエラーは発生しなくなると思います。

(修正前)

```
data = [v for v in reader]
```

(修正後)

```
data = np.asarray([v for v in reader], dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: kei Minagawaさん　返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。ご回答いただいた方法でも試してみたところうまくいきました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @山口龍馬 さん:どういたしまして！